# $V$ is finite dimensional iff $V'$ with the weak topology is normable

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, weak-convergence

Why is the following statement valid?  Note, $V$ is locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $V'$ is the space of all continuous linear maps from $V \to \mathbb{C}$.

$V$ is finite dimensional if and only if $V'$ with the weak topology is normable.

I believe that since $V$ is finite dimensional then $V'$ is finite dimensional.  Thus all topologies on $V'$ are the same and $V'$ is normable.  However, the other direction I am clueless as to the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clue: If $V’$ is infinite dimensional, then for every finite set $F\subset V’’$ of functionals $\bigcap \{\ker: f\in F\}$ should be a non-zero subspace which, therefore can not be contained in a ball $\{f\in V’:||f||<1\}$.

Comment: How do you know "F⊂V′′ of functionals ⋂{ker:f∈F} should be a non-zero subspace"

Comment: It seems that this subspace is an intersection of finitely many subspaces of codimension 1. Therefore, it should have a finite codimension.